# how to do $filename=images/$filename2.jpg

Tags: php

I want to do something like this but i dont know how to:

```
$file="4"
$pic="../pics/$file.jpg";
$sound="../sounds/$file.mp3";
```

also I will do something like this

```
$nextpic="../pics/$file+1.jpg";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code section is fine.

The 2nd should be like this:

```
$nextpic="../pics/" . ($file+1) . ".jpg";
```

Or like this

```
$next_file = $file + 1;
$nextpic="../pics/$next_file.jpg";
```

Answer (score 2):

If your file is a number, PHP will treat it as such regardless if it's a string or what. So you can do:

```
$nextpic = "../pics/".($file+1).".jpg";
```

As an aside, one of PHP's quirks is how it handles strings with numerals in them. For example if you have a file "123lolz.jpg" and you increment it, you will get unwanted results. Silly stuff...

```
$file = "123lolz.jpg";
echo ($file+1)."\n"; // you get 124 and the rest of the file is discarded
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$nextpic="../pics/" . ($file+1) . ".jpg";
```

Since you are adding something you need to take it out as variable replacement with operators do not work within a string.

Answer (score 0):

PHP.net has full documentation for [when/how variables are substituted with their values in strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). In these cases in particular:

```
$file="4"
$pic="../pics/$file.jpg";
$sound="../sounds/$file.mp3";
```

This will produce `$pic = "../pics/4.jpg"` and `$sound="../sounds/4.mp3"`

```
$nextpic="../pics/$file+1.jpg";
```

That will produce `$nextpic="../pics/4+1.jpg"`. If you want 5.jpg use this:

```
$nextpic="../pics/".($file+1).".jpg";
```